# How to sensibly calculate effect sizes for linear mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-models, emmeans

I ran a linear mixed model analysis on my data and specified a rather "simple" LMM. The data come from a within-subject design were participants rated the same stimulus in three different conditions using two questions. The model structure looks like this:

```r
DV ~ Condition * Question + (1 + Condition + Question | Participant)
```

Condition and question are both dummy coded variables with 3 (Condition) and 2 (Question) levels. I get a significant result for the fixed effect of Condition (but not Question and also no interaction between the two).

I analyze which of my 3 levels in `Condition` differ from each other and use the `emmeans()` function to compute contrasts. I see that Condition 1 differs from Condition 2 and from Condition 3.

Now I wanted to calculate an effect size for these differences and I used the `eff_size()` function to do so. However, the effect sizes I get in the output seem way too big. E.g. for my contrasts comparing Condition 1 and 2 my estimate (which equals the mean difference of both Conditions) has a t-value of 4.795. When calculating the effect size "per hand" I get two values. If I use the formula for drm (`Mean2 - Mean1 / SW`; where `SW = Sdiff / sqrt(2(1-r)`) I get a `d` of `d = 0.946`. If I use the t-value and calculate d by using `d = t/sqrt(N)` I get an even smaller value of `d = 0.692`.

But using `eff_size()` from emmeans() results in a `d = 1.59`.

What is the "correct" way for me to get an approximation of `d` as an effect size in this scenario?

Comment: What did you specify as `sigma` and `edf`? `sigma(fit)` and `df.residual(fit)`? Can you be a little more specific in your question and remind us what `Sdiff` and `r` are?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As sigma I specified my model --> e.g. model = lmer(DV ~ Condition * Question + (1 + Condition + Question | Participant)) & sigma = sigma(model). as edf I specified the smallest df I got for my contrasts. However, I was under the impression, that the edf specification is rather uncritical and only influences the CIs and not the effectsize itself. Sdiff I was referring to is the standard deviation of the differences. r is the correlation between the repeated measures of the DV.